# What did the handmaiden call Daenerys Targaryen?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I'm very new to GoT and I'm still struggling to put the characters together.  When her handmaiden is teaching Daenerys how to please her hew husband she called her something - "Ceici"?

Where does this name come from?

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at.  Are you talking about her title of "Khaleesi"?

Comment: Which episode was this?

Comment: @Tom77 S1E2 I believe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doreah and the rest of the hand maidens and Dothraki call Daenerys "Khaleesi", since she is the wife of *Khal* Drogo. It roughly means queen in the Dothraki language.

Answer (score 13):

A **khaleesi** is a wife of the **khal**. This does not roughly translate to queen, since the *khal* is a warlord or a commander. The title is an act of respect, as is *ser* or *lady* in westeros.

Comment: no, the question here is where the word comes from. the flagged answer assumes an incorrect assumption that khaleesi means queen.

Comment: Khal does translate into "king" as seen in phrases used degrade Viserys (Khal Rhae Mhar = Sore Foot King, and Khal Rhaggat = Cart King).  So, I believe the accepted answer is correct. What else is a queen besides "the wife of a king" in a time/culture where Queens have no ruling power.